# Raspberry Pi 2 not booting connected to network

Tags: boot, pi-2

I bought the Raspberry Pi 2 last week. When booted without Ethernet cable plugged in it works fine. When I connect the cable to Ethernet port on Pi, it simply does not boot. The lights below Ethernet port will be on.

Comment: You should include a description of what you mean by "does not boot".  If there's a problem, the green ACT light will blink repeatedly in a regular pattern (e.g., 7 blinks, pause, 7 blinks, pause...).  If it just blinks twice, ostensibly it *did* at least boot the kernel, in which case you should get some output if you plug in a monitor.  This will provide a clue.  If the ethernet lights are on, almost certainly the kernel did boot because that requires an OS to work.

Comment: What are the power and act lights doing (red and green)

Answer (score 1):

That is most likely a power issue. Check that your supply is giving at least 5v@700ma. I would recommend more current. Depending on what devices you have attached you may need a power supply with a current rating of 1 amp or more. Also, sometimes those adapters have faulty and misleading labels. If you have a multimeter check the two test points to make sure the right voltage is getting to your pi.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was the eth0 device being set to "auto", if that is changed to "allow-hotplug" it will boot without eth0 being connected.

Edit /etc/network/interfaces to make this change.